# jsp get ip address

Tags: java, jsp

whats the best way of preventing someone from voting twice? How do i get the users ip address? What if they are on a large network? will everyone on that network show the same ip? thanks

---

UPDATE: request.getRemoteAddr() and request.getRemoteHost() return the Server names, not the client's host name and ip. Anyone else got any bright ideas?

---

Ok, so lets forget about the voting twice thing. Im just trying to get the users ip address? i tried request.getRemoteAddr() and request.getRemoteHost() and think im getting the servers address. I have access to two separate networks and am getting the same IP address :(

Answer (score 9):

In your JSP, use **request.getRemoteAddr()**. This returns the IP address of the agent that sent the request as a String.

Also, **request.getRemoteHost()** will attempt to get the fully qualified host name. If it can't resolve the name however, the IP address will be returned as in **getRemoteAddr()**.

Answer (score 2):

If users are behind [NAT router](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) or [proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server), you will see them with the same IP address. Therefore, it is not the best way of allowing users to vote once.

An alternative would be to use [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), but again, it is possible to erase the cookie and vote again.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the ONLY way of preventing a second vote is by authenticating. Obviously this is not always possible, so you have to mitigate the possibility of a single user casting a ton of votes.

- Throttle the voting by source IP. Use the [getRemoteAddr()](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr()) to allow, say... a vote per hour?... per minute? ... it will depend on how much voting you expect. Adjust the number according to experience.
- Plant a [cookie](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie(javax.servlet.http.Cookie)) on the response for every voting poll, which expires after the ballot closes.
- Make it harder to forge requests by checking and validating headers like `Referer` and `User-Agent`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the IP of a client behind a router/firewall you can use 
`request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")`.

> The X-Forwarded-For (XFF) HTTP header
>   is a de facto standard for identifying
>   the originating IP address of a client
>   connecting to a web server through an
>   HTTP proxy or load balancer.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Keep in mind though, that this value can be changed by the proxies between you and the client. Though it *should* be the correct IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IP address with request.getRemoteAddr(). If the network is using a NAT router, all users will get the same address though

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP page simply use this expression: `${pageContext.request.remoteAddr}`