# a method that returns a ip of machine that access web app

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp web application hosted on a machine hosted in localhost.

I can access this web application from another machine on LAN. 
 What I'm doing here is I created a bean class which has a method that returns a IP of machine   that access web app.
 But when i was accessing from another machine I got the IP of hosted  machine itself .
 Can anyone tell why it happens? Tell me how can I get the IP of another machine that accesses web app hosted in local host.

Comment: and "a method that returns a ip of machine that access web app" is .... ?

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718785/jsp-get-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> getRemoteAddr

method of ServletRequest. Refer to [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably do so, but if you can control the network between all clients and servers, and if you're willing to accept that malicious requests may feed you false information, then there are methods available like [ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29) that will give you information of that sort. To reiterate, it's by no means guaranteed to be the address of the machine that originally sent the request, and it's also guaranteed to be authentic in any way. Given the right (or wrong?) network conditions, it's easy to spoof that piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

this is using a web service to get you the IP address
take a look

```
package ipInfo;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class ExternalIp {
    private static String URL = "http://api-sth01.exip.org/?call=ip";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExternalIp ipGetter = new ExternalIp();
        ipGetter.getExternalIp();
    }

    public void getExternalIp() 
    {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line = "";
        int tries = 0;
        do {    
            try {
                reader = read(URL);
                /*while(reader.readLine() != null)
                {
                    line = line + reader.readLine();
                }*/
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
                System.out.println("File not found for url: " + URL);
                System.out.println("Check your typing");
                System.out.println();
                return;
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Got IO Exception, tries = " + (tries + 1));
                System.out.println("Message: " + ioe.getMessage());
                tries++;
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(300000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                continue;
            }   
            catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (reader == null && tries < 5);

        if (line != null && line.length() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Your external ip address is: " + line);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, couldn't get your ip address");
        }
    }

    public BufferedReader read(String url) throws Exception{
        return new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                new URL(url).openStream()));
    }

}
```