# How to read client's machine IPV4 address?

Tags: javascript, java, applet

How can I read client's machine IP address from browser? Specially I need to do it for Internet Explorer as we're running our application for intranet. I can get machine name using below code -

```
var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
console.log(network.computerName);
```

Any solution/idea is much appreciated. I am fine with applet/any server side coding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any online service can be used such as this [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net/json/):

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
  datatype: 'json',
  method: 'get',
  success: function(data) {
    $('pre').html("IP Addr::::" + data.ip);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I already given a try for this which actually gives server/network proxy IP, not the client system IP. And one more thing these free urls are blocked inside organization due to security reason.

Comment: @KrishSmith Then you can serve the IP in your script you are referring in the object.

Answer (score 1):

One should use this if client is behind a proxy or firewall

`request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")`

If Client is not using proxy or is not behind any firewall than

```
request.getRemoteAddr();
```

should work fine
SO finally summing up the whole code should be

```
String ipAddress  = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
if(ipAddress == null)
{
  ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
System.out.println("ipAddress:"+ipAddress);
```

You should checkout these links
[jsp get ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718785/jsp-get-ip-address)
http://www.coderanch.com/t/293684/JSP/java/client-IP-address-Domain-Java

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if you could do that using ActiveXObject, but if you could include server side? with php you could achieved it using

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

or java/jsp using

```
<%=request.getRemoteAddr()%>
```

Comment: <%=request.getRemoteAddr()%> Using this we get the server IP address or the network proxy behind which actual client system is sitting.

Comment: you get the ip of remote client connecting to your server